# Regular expression to find in Sublime Text

Tags: json, parsing, sublimetext

I need to find all cases in a large json file in a text editor called sublime text

`"lsid" : { "id" : UUID("03006811") },`

where instead of 03006811 there can be anything.
And then replace.

I tried `"lsid":\s*{[^}]+}"` and some other ways but unsuccessful.
Expecting to find all 487 cases with all different values instead 03006811 and then want to replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following pattern should match `"lsid" : { "id" : UUID("03006811") }` and it will work for any other alphanumeric value inside the UUID as well

```
"lsid"\s*:\s*\{\s*"id"\s*:\s*UUID\("([0-9a-fA-F]+)"\)\s*\}
```